# Arduino stereo VU meter

Tags: c++, audio, arduino

I want to create an audio VU meter using Arduino Nano and 5 LED for each channel.
 The problem is that I can't find / create program that do this.

### Code

```
//STEREO LED VU
const int leftLedCount = 5;
const int rightLedCount = 5;
const int leftLed[leftLedCount] = {2,3,4,5,6};
const int rightLed[rightLedCount] = {7,8,9,10,11};
int leftInput, l;
int rightInput, r;
void setup()
{
  for (l = 0; l < leftLedCount; l++)
    pinMode(leftLed[l], OUTPUT);
  for (r = 0; r < rightLedCount; r++)
    pinMode(rightLed[r], OUTPUT);
  testLEDs();
}
void testLEDs()
{
  for (l = 0; l < leftLedCount; l++)
    digitalWrite(leftLed[l], HIGH);
  for (r = 0; r < rightLedCount; r++)
    digitalWrite(rightLed[r], HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  turnOffLEDs();
}
void turnOffLEDs()
{  
  for (l = 0; l < leftLedCount; l++)
    digitalWrite(leftLed[l], LOW);
  for (r = 0; r < rightLedCount; r++)
    digitalWrite(rightLed[r], LOW);
}
void loop()
{
  leftInput = analogRead(A0)/12,5;
  rightInput = analogRead(A1)/12,5;
  //LEFT
  for(l=0; l <= leftInput; l++)
  {
    digitalWrite(leftLed[l], HIGH);
  }
  //RIGHT
  for(r=0; r <= rightInput; r++)
  {
    digitalWrite(rightLed[r], HIGH);
  }
  //TURN OFF LEDS
  turnOffLEDs();
}
```

Problems:

- after a few minutes it's totally stop working: randomly a few LED keeps ON
- the light is not related to the sound

I think the problem is with changing the input level because I don't understand how should be distributed the signal level. Any kind of little help would be helpful.

Comment: @KillzoneKid With this section I want to get a value from 0 to 5. But why would this be equal to 5?

Comment: Actually `leftInput = analogRead(A0)/12,5;` will be interpreted as `leftInput = analogRead(A0)/12;` as coma has lower [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than assignment. Fixing that will not solve the problem, so please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted to write `12.5` instead of `12,5` in these expressions:  `leftInput = analogRead(A0)/12,5; rightInput = analogRead(A1)/12,5;` But even then, the `analogRead` returns value from `0` to `1023` (including). So the value for `left/rightInput` would range from `0` to about `81`, while you need it to be in range of `0...4`. I suggest to have another array of threshold values and depending on the strength of the signal light up all LEDs that are above threshold, for example (not tested) add this instead of your `loop()`:

```
const int thresholdsLeftLed[leftLedCount] = { 4, 208, 412, 616, 820 };
const int thresholdsRightLed[rightLedCount] = { 4, 208, 412, 616, 820 };

void LightLEDs(int signalLeft, int signalRight)
{
    for (int l = 0; l < leftLedCount; ++l)
        digitalWrite(leftLed[l], signalLeft > thresholdsLeftLed[l] ? HIGH : LOW);
    for (int r = 0; r < rightLedCount; ++r)
        digitalWrite(rightLed[r], signalRight > thresholdsRightLed[r] ? HIGH : LOW);
}

void loop()
{
    LightLEDs(analogRead(A0), analogRead(A1));
}
```

Note that you probably don't need to turn all LEDs off as they are turned off in the loop if the signal is below threshold

Comment: I've changed the thresholds a bit, otherwise it's perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes they are linear but I thought maybe making them more logarithmic would look better. Glad it worked out.